# Getting method to run in the background from remote notification

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, apple-push-notifications, firebase-notifications

I'm using Firebase Messaging (Notifications) to send push reminders to users on iOS. For my app, that is a todo app, I'm using Swift 3. When the user gets the push notification I want them to be able to complete the task right from the push notification.

Everything works almost great. The user gets the push. When they 3d-touch they see the "complete button". When the "complete button" is tapped the didReceive response method in the app is triggered in the background.

**Now to the problem,** in that method I'm using a closure and then a closure in that closure. For some reason the first part of the code runs in the background without the user opening the app but the last part is only running when the user opens the app again (see below). Why is that?

**This is my code:**

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo

    if response.actionIdentifier == notificationActionComplete, let actionKey = userInfo["actionKey"] as? String {
        getAction(actionKey: actionKey, completion: { (action) in
            action.complete {

            }
        })
    }

    completionHandler()
}

func getAction(actionKey: String, completion:@escaping (Action)->Void) {
    Database.database().reference(withPath: "actions/\(actionKey)").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        let action = Action(snapshot: snapshot)
        completion(action)
    })
}
```

**In action class:**

```
var ref: DatabaseReference?

init(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
    key = snapshot.key
    ref = snapshot.ref

    //Other inits here
}

func complete(completion:@escaping (Void) -> Void) {
    //This code to remove the node is running fine in background
    ref.removeValue { (error, ref) in
        //The code in here is not running until the user opens the app next time
        otherRef.updateChildValues(self.toAnyObject(), withCompletionBlock: { (error, ref) in
        completion()        
    })
}
```

Comment: Does the program completely stop when getting to the code that does not run or is it merely skipping it and reaching the final `completionHandler()` in `userNotificationCenter(_:didReceiveResponse)`?

Comment: Can you update your question and show the declaration of `getAction`?

Comment: What is `ref` ? And how are removing node?

Comment: You have to check the application state. you have to run   2 blocks of code one for foreground and else for background.

Comment: @matiastofteby see updated question above

Comment: @matiastofteby it reaches the completionHandler() in userNotificationCenter(_:didReceiveResponse). Its just the closure otherRef.updateChildValues that never finish.

Comment: I think that the otherRef.updateChildValues takes some time to run and for some reason it stops running when something takes too long time when running in background. Can that be the case?

Comment: code seems a bit strange: completionHandler at bottom is will be a callback to OS code when You are done. So I usually call it after doing all my stuff. If You trigger a (delayed) code (in other custom completion handlers...) you must pass it ans execute it in LAST piece of code. (otherwise you are telling iOS: "I am done" and it consider your task done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app is basically suspended after the runloop cycle where userNotificationCenter() is called, so if your completion handler is in response to asynchronous work, that work will never happen until your app resumes again.  To get around this you will probably need to begin a background task inside that function, and then have your completion handler end the background task when it is finished.  This tells the system you need to stay alive for a while in the background (although it is not guaranteed, if you take too long)

See "Executing Finite Limit Tasks" at this URL (sorry, it's Obj-C, but there should be a Swift way to do it too):

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html